# Surjective implies right inverse

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inverse-function

I already know how to prove that if the function $f$ has a right inverse, it implies that $f$ is surjective. But how can I prove that if $f$ is surjective it has a right inverse in a formal way?

Comment: Sorry, I downgraded my answer to a comment below, because I did not realize the subtlety of the question. Very embarrassing of me. I'll just reiterate what I wrote, because it would be helpful nonetheless.

Comment: If $f: A\rightarrow B$ is surjective, then for any $b\in B$ there exists an element $a\in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. This fact is needed to _define/construct_ a possible function $g:B\rightarrow A$ such that $f(g(b)) = b$ for all $b\in B$. The way to do this is using the axiom of choice.

Comment: I believe this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1076140) and the question within the link have the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @SpiralRain . Good link. In fact "$\forall f\, (f$ is surjective iff $f$ has a right inverse)" is equivalent to AC